# Fan turns on full blast after resuming from suspend - Sony Vaio w/ Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, suspend, fancontrol

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 
Laptop: Sony E-Series SVE14A37CDH.
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series Hybrid GPU.

I installed the proprietary AMD Catalyst drivers from:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

I followed this tutorial: [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513)

When I switch to the integrated Intel GPU (using the Catalyst Control Center) it works fine until I suspend and resume.  At this point the fan powers up full speed and does not stop. The CPU load is very low and laptop is cool.

This only happens while using the Intel GPU, and does not happen when Radeon GPU is enabled.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: **I just did a fresh install, turned off discrete GPU with vgaswitcheroo using only the default drivers (no fglrx installed at any point) and the problem still happens.  When the computer returns form suspend, the fan revs up and doesn't stop.**

Comment: Could you post the output of `dmesg` right when this happens? It might show some hints as to what is causing the problem. Does the laptop continue to work when the fan problem occurs?

Comment: The laptop does continue to work normally, the only issue is the fan.  The output of the dmesg can be found here:  http://filebin.ca/n0WfFeItMjc

Comment: Is there any other information I could provide to help someone to help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the following solution that fixed a very similar problem for me (hybrid graphics Intel HD 3000 and AMD Radeon HD 6630M) will also work for you. As you're writing about switcheroo I asume you're using the open source ati driver like me. I added the following script to 
**/etc/pm/sleep.d**
 called **0001fixhibernate**

> gksudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/0001fixhibernate

and added this text:

```
#/bin/sh

case "$1" in

    suspend|hibernate)
        echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
        echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
        ;;
    resume|thaw)
        echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
        echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

What the script does is activating the discrete graphics card just before suspend or hibernation and disables it again on resuming or thawing.
With this script I'm working around a freeze after resuming that's accompanied by the fan running at full speed. Please give any feedback if it works or not.